# Heroku constantly change url for my heroku-redis addon

Tags: django, heroku, redis, heroku-redis

Im using the heroku-redis addon as a message broker for my django app, which is hosted on a VPS. The problem is that Heroku constantly change de URL of the service, so my app keep crashing from time to time, when the url is changed.

Anyone knows a way to fix this? Is there a way of getting automatically the updated URL for my  heroku-redis addon?

Answer (score 2):

From heroku-redis [provisioning docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-redis#provisioning-the-add-on)

In order for Heroku to manage this add-on for you and respond to a variety of operational situations, the **REDIS config vars may change at any time**. **Relying on the config var outside of your Heroku app may result in you having to re-copy the value if it changes**.

Just use `REDIS_URL` env variable in your settings to always get correct URL

Comment: But my django app is hosted outside Heroku, so i cant access that variable directly. I know that one option might be to give access to my heroku cli to my vps, to get the variable, but doesnt seem like a good practice.

Comment: why do you use heroku redis if your app is not hosted there, you probably introduce lot of latency as cache is far from your VPS anyways ( you could install redis on vps). Unfortunately there is no watcher for link change,  you can get private link on heroku-redis only when you spend 900$/month for private xD